# Is anyone looking into the untagged tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the un-tagging of the [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag happening?
There are currently 120 questions tagged [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

What are we going to do with these?
I assume we will need a shiny diamond special user to handle them, seeing as how some of them are locked for historical significance.

Comment: Personnaly I dont see that tag as a problem, but it's my opinion, as it's not a error, it's untagged

Comment: @yagmoth555 The purpose of tags: `A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions.`. How does `untagged` do that right now?

Comment: Most of them closed are off-topic, how correcting offtopic question help us ? someday the system will simply purge them anyhow

Comment: @yagmoth555 My main concern is that if you leave a mistake alone in the wild, it will grow. In this case, if you leave the tag out there, people will use it. And seeing as how it is meaningless now, yet has a lot of questions tagged, it is likely to pop up. Looking at newest questions with the tag, people are indeed using it.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I also thought that the system will never purge them because they are locked for historical significance as part of Hopeless` work. I guess your opinion is to just leave the mess as is and let time run its course?

Comment: Yes for closed question, but your point is good to educate the user to prevent that tag use if we decide to not use it. As like I thought, it's more regular that use it, like seen in that example; http://serverfault.com/posts/507875/revisions

Comment: But my opinion is that tag is good, as it's like someone that put is hand in the air to get help to classify the question, but need the community to help him

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is very useful, as it is a clear indication that a question is in need of some attention.  The specific attention that most of the questions that have the tag need is burnination -- even the ones that are open are crap questions (I have *no* idea how that "R" question is still alive).

I don't think that it is an issue of people using the tag (you cannot create a question without any tags, nor can you explicitly specify [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) when creating or editing a question; I just tried it and the system told me off).  It does, on the other hand, make the place look a bit untidy and unmaintained.

If some kind souls want to start weeding the garden, and let me know which questions need shiny diamond powers, I'll help out where needed.

Comment: does your *shiny diamond powers* offer from sept 2015 still stand? If so, please consider my suggestions in my answer I just posted ...

Comment: Yep, I can take care of those.  Sorry about the delay in answering, I've been moving house across the country.

Comment: OK, great, enjoy weeding!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/840855/untagged-questions-networkwide) which compares the number of untagged questions across different Stack Exchange site. It turns out that ServerFault is *really* an outlier with over 500 questions; there's no other site with more than 100 untagged questions and only two others with more than 50.

[image]

Comment: Hi, good query, I would see that as a question edit too maybe, as technically that mean the tag use is growing, it was at 120 before in 2015, now at 556. What we do ? as a lot of those question are locked, thus it will need a moderator privilege to clean.

Comment: Thanks. I can't edit the question, you need full edit privileges to do so. I understand this does not really answer the question, but as is often the case in [discussion] posts on Meta, I'm just throwing in my 2 cents, and this could (later) serve as a progress report if the community succeeds in cleaning up the tag. I've suggested half a dozen tag edits but the rest of the questions are closed or even locked, as you mention.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Something else must have been happening. In April 2016 there were [11](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422213426/https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions left. In June 2016 the tag had been [deleted](https://web.archive.org/web/20160623024257/https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged). In August 2016 there were [580](https://web.archive.org/web/20160823040102/https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged). And of the remaining 550 none have been edited since [February 2015](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged?sort=active).

Comment: @yagmoth555 Even more interesting. If we look at the most recently modified among those questions, it did in fact have the tag in [June 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609193306/https://serverfault.com/questions/178308/the-real-world-systems-architect-and-systems-administrator-what-is-the-diffe) between the date where there were 11 left (and that question wasn't one of them) and the date where the tag had been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Some months ago I stumbled on this specific meta question, and couldn't believe how much the [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag was abused on this specific site. A few days ago, I found some time to somehow try to "contribute" to cleaning this up a bit (note: I had only a rep of about +300 when I started ...). Here is what I achieved since Jan 17, 2015:

- These are these stats as of today:

  - [**579** locked untagged questions](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20is%3Aq%20locked%3Ayes) (= **+1** since sept 21, 2015, obviously out of my control because of my rep).
  - [[untagged] closed:no locked:no](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano) only returns **5** more hits.
  - [[untagged] closed:yes locked:no](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20closed%3Ayes%20locked%3Ano)  only returns **9** more hits.
  - So for the unlocked questions, the counter went down from **114** to **5 + 9 = 14** more hits ... That is **100 questions** that got resolved (and also explains my +100*2 rep increase since I started ...).
- For the remaining **14** unlocked questions, I probably won't do any additional efforts to also get those resolved, mostly because of either of those reasons:

  - I don't understand why [retagging a duplicate "untagged" question](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/245904) with the very same tag (as the duplicate) gets ... rejected! If, IMHO, question 1 is classified as a duplicate of question 2, then their tags should be identical also (instead of one of them having "untagged" as tag, go figure ...).
  - Check for yourself if "you" have any inspiration about which tag to use for the remaining ([closed:no](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano) and [closed:yes](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20closed%3Ayes%20locked%3Ano)) ones ... I've really tried to find "some" tag, but about 4 of them for which I had (I thought) found a tag my suggested edit got rejected. So be it, I'm not going to take a risk of running into a suggested edits ban ... By the way, after you complete the closed:yes and closed:no questions, you should see [a few more questions which seem to not be closed:no and also not be closed:yes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) ... (what am I missing, `closed:maybe` ???).
- Here are "some" (hm, hm) suggestions to also further reduce the 579 remaining locked questions with **52** more (less?) [untagged](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions (= about 10%):

  - [[untagged] is:q phpmyadmin](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20is%3Aq%20phpmyadmin%20locked%3Ayes) (**2** remaining, retag with [phpmyadmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin)?).
  - [[untagged] is:q plesk](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Buntagged%5D%20plesk%20is%3Aq) (**4** remaining, retag with [plesk](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/plesk)?).
  - [[untagged] is:q cpanel](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20is%3Aq%20cpanel) (**5** remaining, retag with [cpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cpanel)?).
  - [[untagged] is:q inventory](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20inventory%20is%3Aq) (**7** remaining, retag with [asset-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asset-management)?).
  - [[untagged] is:q outsourcing](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20outsourcing%20is%3Aq) (**5** remaining, retag with [hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hosting)?).
  - [[untagged] duplicate:yes](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20duplicate%3Ayes) (**22** remaining , use **same tag** as the duplicate question?).
  - [[untagged] is:q mcse](https://serverfault.com/search?q=[untagged]%20is%3Aq%20mcse) (**7** remaining, retag with [test](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/test) ... or something better?).

PS 1: In Dutch (the language I learned on my mother's knees ...) we have a saying that sounds more or less like so:

> Many have dreams, only a few wake up and work on making them happen ...

Hope my answer will wake up "somebody" (with "*shiny diamond powers*" ???) to further reduce (at least) those 14 not-locked and 52 locked questions.

PS 2: Merci (oeps: thank you) to all the suggested edits reviewers over the past few days who approved those about 100 suggestions. And for those who rejected some of them: don't worry, I understand (one can't have 100% approval rates ...).

Comment: [Review question: Retagging of old closed untagged questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8585/review-question-retagging-of-old-closed-untagged-questions)

Comment: @Iain : merci for the link in your comment, can you clarify a bit WHAT you are you trying to say by posting that link? Also, I trust the description of the untagged tag is ... correct, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Must be, I'll have to ask my wife (she's from Limburg ;) )

Comment: Aha, then she must also know "Ik ben Limburger, ... en daar ben ik fier op!"