# Help with mass retagging of FTP related posts

Tags: support, retag-request

As discussed [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8588/many-old-questions-getting-additional-proftpd-vsftpd-tags/), I've been going through posts tagged with "ftp", and adding FTP server-specific tags (*e.g.* "proftpd", "pureftpd", and "vsftpd") where relevant.  There are many such posts, and the retagging caused old posts to appear on the front page unnecessarily.

What's the best way to get these old posts retagged, *en masse*, without causing issues?

I currently have a list 542 posts that I'd like to nominate/suggest for retagging; listing each of those posts here seems a bit much.  What's the best way to coordinate such a thing?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: To build up the list of suggested edits, I first looked at all posts (newest to oldest) tagged with "ftp", and looked for posts asking about FTP server implementations (when specific servers are mentioned) and their issues.  Some of the posts had the maximum 5 tags, and some already had been tagged with the server implementation.  I skipped over any post marked "closed".

For many of these posts, the question/answer are not specific to the
server implementation in question.  However, many users looking for these
questions *may assume that the answers are specific to those implementations*, and thus applying these tags can hopefully help those users find the answers they seek.

I suspect that many of these posts predate the existence of the relevant tags.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way to get these old posts retagged, en masse, without causing issues?

There isn't one, until you get enough rep that your edits are auto-approved and you therefore have control over when your edits will "bump" the a thread to the top of the active view.

So long as your edits need to be approved by people going through the review queue, there is nothing *you* can do to make a mass editing or mass retagging project less disruptive to the active view.

Comment: That's fine; is there some way to enlist the aid of a moderator, or someone who can make these changes (assuming they're approved)?  I'm not particular about _myself_ doing the changes; I'd just like to contribute this as part of helping to organize these FTP-related posts.

Comment: @TJSaunders *<shrug>*  That would just shift the disruption to a moderator, which is not an improvement.  I personally think you're worrying too much. SE doesn't care about it enough to anything to fix it (it's been a well known issue for years), and there aren't enough quality questions or participation from whatever's left of the community on ServerFault that disrupting the active view makes much of a difference anyway. Now the active view is flooded with recently edited questions about ftp, rather than the usual flood of completely useless crap. Having a hard time finding a problem in that.